# Wire resistivity

Tags: wire, resistivity

Could you please shed some light on wire resistivity calculations for me....

for example if you have a wire length at 100m with a diameter of 10mm measured at 0.25 ohms.(what material is 0.25?? I can do the calculation if it was copper for example: 1.68 x 10^-8 )

formula is \$R = \dfrac{\rho × l}{A}\$

0.25?? x 100 = ??

area \$A = \pi × 5^2 = 75.53\$

??? / 75.53 = ??

Answer (score 3):

\$R = ρ l / A\$

Where

- \$R\$ is resistance in ohms (\$\Omega\$)
- \$ρ\$ is resistivivity of the material in ohm meters. (\$\Omega m\$)
- \$l\$ is the length of the object in meters (\$m\$)
- \$A\$ is the cross-sectional area of the object in square meters (\$m^2\$).

As you say, copper has a resistivity of \$1.68×10^{−8}\$ ohm meters.

Your (uniform cylindrical) wire has

- length \$l\$ = 100 meters,
- diameter = 10 mm = 0.01 meters
- \$\therefore\$ radius = 0.01 / 2 meters
- \$\therefore\$ cross-sectional area \$A\$ = \$\pi r^2 = \pi (0.01 / 2)^2 = 7.85×10^{-5} m^2\$
- resistance \$R\$ = 0.25 ohms.

To determine resistivity you transform the equation \$R = ρ l / A\$ by dividing each side by \$l\$ and multiplying each side by \$A\$

this gives \$R A / l = ρ\$

You get the resistivity of the material by replacing the \$R\$, \$A\$ and \$l\$ by the values you have above and doing the arithmetic.

Comment: I get confused with  cross-sectional area A = πr2=π(0.01/2)2=7.85×10−5m2

Comment: I get confused with  cross-sectional area A = πr2=π(0.01/2)2=7.85×10−5m2   when I do this on the calculator it shows as (pi x 0.01/2 ^2)  7.853981634x10^-3  why is it showing 10x -3 and not 10x -5???

Comment: @john: I would put the calculator in the drawer (or trash can!), do rough calculations in my head, rounding everything to 1 significant digit: **think about five thousandths x 5 thousandths = 25 millionths then multiply by 3 = 75 millionths = \$75 x 10^{-6} = 7.5 x 10^{-5}\$**. I find it a good habit to do basic arithmetic in my head to reality check my fumble-fingered use of electronic brain-crutches.

Answer (score 1):

Specific resistivity is expressed in Ωm. I.e. it's the resistance of 1 m length and 1 m\$^2\$ cross section. To calculate back from your 0.25 Ω you have to divide by 100 m -> 2.5 mΩ/m and multiply by the cross section in m\$^2\$: 0.005\$^2\$ π = 7.85 x 10\$^-5\$ m\$^2\$.
Multiplying both: 2.5 x 10\$^-3\$ Ω/m x 7.85 x 10\$^-5\$ m\$^2\$ = 2 x 10\$^-7\$ Ωm.